# Given BlobKey of video how to get url

Tags: google-app-engine, video, mp4, blobstore

Normally, to get a url from a BlobKey, I simply do

```
public static String getUrlFromKey(BlobKey blobKey) {
    if(null == blobKey)return null;
    ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey).secureUrl(false);
    String servingUrl = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
    return servingUrl;
  }
```

But I am now getting an exception and I am convince that the reason is because this time the Blobkey is for a video instead of an image. So how do I get the url given the Blobkey of a video?

For some background, I am using a Cloud Endpoint App-Engine server for my Android app. after uploading a video to the Blobstore, I need to be able to watch it from my android device. So if there is no way to get the url the way I can with an image, is there a way to serve it from an endpoint method?

Error:

```
com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFailureException: 
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.getServingUrl(ImagesServiceImpl.java:284)
    at com.mycompany.utils.BlobstoreUtils.getUrlFromKey(BlobstoreUtils.java:21)
    at com.mycompany.servlet.VideoUploadCallback.doPost(VideoUploadCallback.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:147)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:457)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> To serve blobs, you must include a blob download handler as a path in
>   your application. This handler should pass the blob key for the
>   desired blob to blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);. In this
>   example, the blob key is passed to the download handler as the URL
>   argument (req.getParameter('blob-key')). In practice, the download
>   handler can get the blob key by any means you choose, such as through
>   another method or user action.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws IOException {
        BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
        blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```

Look at using Google Cloud Storage instead of Blobstore. Then you can serve your videos directly - simply by passing the URL of a video, without going through your application.

Comment: When it comes to image, I serve them without all that. I just give the url to whomever wants to see the image (i.e. android/ios client). I will look at cloud storage.

Comment: From your experience, any gotchas I should be aware of when working with datastore, android, and cloud storage together? I mean how does cloud storage play with those?

Comment: To be more specific: things like `Google API Client Libraries` vs `Google Cloud Client Libraries` in android

Comment: How do you get the url of the video for the Cloud Storage solution?

Comment: I unmarked the response as the answer because you mention that if I use the Cloud Storage then I can simply pass the URL to the client, but you don't show how I would do that. The servlet thing you mention I was already aware of: unfortunately I cannot use it with an endpoint but have to use a proper servlet which is not the answer I was seeking. In any case if you can complete your response about the URL, then that would be very helpful. Sorry for the miscommunication.